# Brew commands equivalent for Chocolatey app powershell app

Tags: shell, cmd, windows-10, chocolatey

How do you see the services that are currently running via a command in **Chocolatey** on window 10.

> The equivalent for this command is on MacOS Brew is

```
$brew services list
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a Windows Operating System, the concept of applications running in the background is built in (in the form of a Windows Service).  As such, there is no real requirement to add this as a command in Chocolatey since getting a list of the currently running Windows Services can be achieved using the `Get-Service` PowerShell cmdlet.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-service?view=powershell-6

For example, if you were interested only in the currently running Windows Services, you would use:

`Get-Service | Where-Object Status -eq "Running"`

I don't really see how Chocolatey, as a Windows Package Manager, could add any real value here.

Comment: I would be very interested in hearing what `Get-Service` does on a Mac. https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell

Comment: I was actually interested in the same thing this morning, so I tested it, but isn't doesn't seem to be implemented on PowerShell Core running on my Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Running services on Windows can be seen using the command:

```
net start
```